# Umbraco routing not working outside Home node

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

To reproduce the issue create the following hierarchy:

- Content

  - Home

    - Foo

      - Bar - The published URL will be `<domain>/foo/bar`
  - Foo

    - Bar - The published URLwill be `<domain>/bar`

Why does  umbraco skip `/foo/` when creating a page outside of Home? Is there a way to make nodes outside of Home stack the path as the nodes under Home?

Umbraco v7

Comment: Check Foo nodes for assigned hostnames, maybe? You can basically set a hostname for any node in the content tree, which can confuse things (if one of the Foo nodes has the "root" website URL set as a hostname, all children URLs will relate to that hostname).

Comment: I've checked my setup and I'm not running a multisite config. No culture or hostnames have been set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to understand what's going on with the help from [Umbraco community](https://our.umbraco.com/forum/using-umbraco-and-getting-started//102753-umbraco-routing-not-working-outside-home-node).

By default umbraco treats each child of Content as a root node aka home page. This is controlled by the following setting in web.config `<add key="Umbraco.Core.HideTopLevelNodeFromPath" value="true" />`

If I would extend my example by adding 3rd level like so: `Content > Foo > Bar > Baz` I would see that the published path of Baz is `/bar/baz`. Umbraco does stack the path but it removes the 1st level because it's considered the default route.

Answer (score 1):

Home is your root node so / will show your home page and /foo/ will show the home>foo page.

The only way to show nodes under the root foo node is to provide a hostname on the root foo node using 'culture and hostnames'

Obviously once you do that, you will also have to set that hostname up as a binding on the same website in iis as well.

It would probably also be good practice to set a hostname for the home node as well if you add one for the foo node